# how do i get a list of names that doesnt have a userName, to another sheet in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am not sure how to get the list of names from a column that has an adjacent empty column to another sheet.
[the names with blank userNames i want to import to sheet13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAfoa.png)

[names imported to sheet13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRXXB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILTER()` function.

```
 =FILTER(B2:B,C2:C="")
```

If you want to filter from other sheet then just use sheet name before range like

```
=FILTER('Copyoftest'!B2:B,'Copyoftest'!C2:C="")
```

You can also use `QUERY()` function like-

```
=QUERY('Copyoftest'!B2:C,"select B where C is null",0)
```

Comment: If it works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it).